# .htaccess conflicting rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to change a website to multi-language, so I have URL's like this:

```
www.company.com/en/about
www.company.com/fr/about
```

which should point to index.php?lang=en&what=about

so I defined the following rewrite rule (which works)

```
RewriteRule    ^en/(.*)$    ?lang=en&what=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^fr/(.*)$    ?lang=fr&what=$2    [NC,L]
```

but I also need the homepage url as `www.company.com/en` (pointing to `index.php?lang=en`)
which does not work for this rule.

The best solution would be something like

```
RewriteRule    ^(.*)/(.*)$    ?lang=$1&what=$2    [NC,L]
```

but it converts all the urls, like `href='css.css'` kind of references, so it messes up the whole page.

so how should I restrict the first GET variable to be two chars? or one of the defined languages?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})(?:/(.*)|)$ /?lang=$1&what=$2 [L]
```

The first grouping, `([a-z]{2})`, captures the 2 letter language. The second optional grouping captures the "what". If there's nothing there, then "what" will be blank.

Comment: Thanks! It works, but I had to change '/?lang..' to '?lang..'